# Regex patterns in Powershell

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

I am trying to retrieve the `guids` of projects within a `.sln` file using `regular expressions`

So, for instance, if I have in the file a project like this:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "SomeProject", "SomeProject\SomeProject.csproj", "{F5EF941A-49AD-404D-9EB1-209A75D4113F}"
EndProject
```

I would do something like this in my script:

```
$projectsInSolution = Select-String "$file" -pattern 'Project' 
$lineProjectsInFile = $projectsInSolution -match " `"{\S*}"
```

In the regular expression, I leave the whitespace because the real guid is `F5EF941A-49AD-404D-9EB1-209A75D4113F`

However, when I run this, I get

`C:\...\...\...\....sln:6:Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "SomeProject", 
"SomeProject\SomeProject.csproj", "{F5EF941A-49AD-404D-9EB1-209A75D4113F}"`

Why I am not getting the guid only?

I tested it in [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) and it seems so be working

Thank you

**Edit**

This is what I am doing now. But, not getting anything

```
$projectsInSolution = Select-String "$solutionFileStr" -pattern 'Project' 
$lineProjectsInFile = $projectsInSolution -match "(?<={)[^}]+(?=}`"\s*EndProject)"

ForEach($line in $lineProjectsInFile)
{
    Write-Output "$line"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue isn't with your RegEx but with how you're running it. Your `Select-String` command outputs a `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo` object, so what you're going to want to match against for that is the `Line` property. Also, if all you want is the GUID, I would use -Replace, and make the GUID a capture group, and replace the entire line with just the capture group. Something like this:

```
$file = 'c:\temp\test.txt'
$projectsInSolution = Select-String "$file" -pattern '^Project'
$lineProjectsInFile = $projectsInSolution.line -replace "^.+ `"{(\S*)}.*$", '$1'
```

That will result in `$lineProjectsInFile` containing an array of strings that are just the project GUIDs.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regex:

```
{(?<GUID>[^}]+)}[^{}]*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tN2oV6/4)

Then you need to access it the following ways:

```
$projectsInSolution = Select-String "$solutionFileStr" -pattern '^Project' 
$guids = $projectsInSolution.line -match "({(?<GUID>[^}]+)}[^{}]*$"
```

Perhaps, this will be enough:

```
select-string -path <file_path> -pattern '({(?<GUID>[^}]+)}[^{}]*$' -allmatches  |
  foreach-object {$_.matches} |
   foreach-object {$_.groups[1].value} |
    Select-Object -Unique
```

Comment: It works in the demo. But it is not returning anything in PowerShell. I'll edit my post to show you what I am doing

Comment: Note this will work only if the example text you provided in the question is passed to the regex engine. Else, if the guid is at the end of the line, you can get it with `(?<={)[^}]+(?=}"$)`.

Comment: Yeah. I don't know Powershell enough. I am probably feeding it with the wrong string. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use a capture group:

```
$Pattern = '\{(?<RealGuid>[0-9A-F]{8}([0-9A-F]{4}){3}[0-9A-F]{12})\}"$'
$RealGuid = Get-Content -Path $file | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match $Pattern){
        $Matches['RealGuid']
    }
}
```